# How to set Woocommerce Shipping Total on Programmatically Created Order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this function to create a new order for my customers...

```
    public function create_order( $user_id, $address, $product_id ) {

        if ( ! $address ) return false;

        $address = array(
          'first_name' => $address->billing_first_name,
          'last_name'  => $address->billing_last_name,
          'email'      => $address->billing_email,
          'phone'      => $address->billing_phone,
          'address_1'  => $address->billing_address_1,
          'city'       => $address->billing_city,
          'state'      => $address->billing_state,
          'postcode'   => $address->billing_postcode,
          'country'    => $address->billing_country
        );

        $default_args = array(
            'status'        => 'wc-pending',
            'customer_id'   => $user_id,
        );

      // Now we create the order
      $order = wc_create_order( $default_args );

      $order->add_product( get_product( $product_id ), 1 ); // This is an existing SIMPLE product

      // set default address to the created order
      $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );

      //calculate total order price
      $order->calculate_totals();

      $order->update_status( "pending", 'Order Created Successfully And Payment is not completed', TRUE );

      return $order;
}
```

This does create a new order but it doesn't calculate shipping cost... See below screenshot

[Created Order Total Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO2Mf.png)

I have flat rate shipping cost based on User Billing State and Total Item QTY.... so how do i set shipping calculation automatically like it happens on checkout..

Comment: You most likely need to add the shipping rate to the cart order and then calculate shipping before you calculate the totals. See [the calculate_shipping() method here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/)

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issues.

Comment: yes i did... do you still need solution... @joelgullander